# Did the U. S.–Mexico border wall actually need 3 weeks for completion?

Tags: united-states, trump-wall, fact-check-request

Donald Trump mentioned to the audience last year at a rally I was in that the Mexican border wall needed 3 weeks for completion, but is there any proof of this?

See the [C-SPAN video](https://www.c-span.org/video/?523891-1/president-trump-campaigns-senator-marco-rubio) at 11:30 to 11:50.

Also, [Business Insider reports](https://www.businessinsider.com/trump-hannity-border-wall-misunderstanding-fox-news-video-2022-1) on January 21, 2022 —

> "So we would've had the wall completed in three weeks," Trump said. "It was largely completed. We did almost 500 miles of wall, and the southern border."

Comment: I am unaware of any land disputes along the U.S−Mexico border, so I'm not sure what sort of "completion" it could require. In any case, this question is probably better directed over at Skeptics.SE.

Comment: The border is very large and details about where the wall in question is are needed to answer this.

Comment: @A.R. This would get closed on skeptics as there needs to be a notable claim and not just something you heard while at a rally.

Comment: @JoeW I would submit that a claim made by a notable person is a notable claim. It's a better fit there than here.

Comment: @A.R. Saying you heard something at a rally isn't an acceptable notable claim for skeptics and it will get closed because of that.

Comment: If you could find a YouTube or a quote from those rallies making this statement, this would probably be on topic for Skeptics.  After all, it is a fairly notable claim when made by a POTUS candidate.  And kudos on you for questioning what you heard from Trump.

Comment: TBH, it's hard to put a real meaning to what Trump says there. It's not your fault, but the claim is probably unverifiable due to Trump's vagueness, at least.

Comment: It [appears](https://www.the-independent.com/news/world/americas/us-politics/trump-border-wall-cpac-mexico-b2024428.html) he was just talking about the 450 or so miles of wall he commissioned as being 3 weeks away from completed when he left office. The whole border is some 1900 miles.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I don't question anything Trump says. I just assume a priori that it's either a lie or stupid. Although he was correct the other day when he pointed out that "us" is spelled U-S.

Comment: https://www.c-span.org/video/?523891-1/president-trump-campaigns-senator-marco-rubio Go to 11:30 in the video. That was the rally I attended where he spoke about the "3 weeks".

Comment: @Fizz of which well more than half is river.

Comment: With the link and quote provided it should now be suitable for skeptics

Comment: The federal government couldn't build a picket fence around a post office in three weeks.

Comment: @Barmar Wise words indeed.  But neither of us probably attend his rallies.  Which the OP did and which makes his curiosity notable (and probably also motivated the early-on downvote).

Comment: @JoeW If Trump becomes re-elected President, we would probably know where the wall is as I believe he is the only one with the answer about the wall's location.

Comment: @Fizz I agree with you in that Trump is vague since we don't know where he's talking about.

Comment: Expecting prevision from Trump is barking up the wrong tree. Remember his "proposal" to replace Obamacare? it was a one-sheet summary.